# How to set up Stripe functions triggers

Tags: stripe-payments

Sorry if there is Stripe documentation for this but after a week of trying to find this in the Stripe documentation I was unable to find any solution.

Is there any way to set up Stripe event triggers internally in Stripe? I know there are Stripe webhooks but this is a solution for external API calls. Other platforms (like Supabase, MongoDB Atlas) usually allow us to "chain" eventsand trigger functions internally in their platform.

Is it also possible to do this in Stripe? My case is to automatically generate and send a credit note to a customer if he/she did not pay the invoice for the next subscription period (i.e. has canceled his/her subscription).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Stripe doesn't support these kinds of internal triggers/events but you still can achieve this using webhooks[1] and by setting your own APIs to build your own business logic.

> My case is to automatically generate and send a credit note to a customer if he/she did not pay the invoice for the next subscription period

You can listen to the event invoice.payment_failed [2] to achieve this for example

If you're thinking about using automation tools instead, I would strongly recommend seeing Zapier[3],Tray[4], Automate[5] or your favorite automation tool for Stripe Connectors/Integration workflow examples.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#payment-failures

[3] https://zapier.com/apps/stripe/integrations

[4] https://tray.io/connectors/stripe-integrations

[5] https://automate.io/integration/stripe

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
This was my concern that the only solution would be to use standard Stripe webhook.